# Impossible to catch exceptions in service layer

Tags: hibernate, rest, exception, try-catch

I have a REST web application.
When performing a PUT request on a resource called `ThingGroup`my controller calls the service layer like that

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public void updateThingGroup(@Valid @RequestBody final ThingGroup thingGroup, final Principal principal) throws UnknownResourceException {
    final User user = userService.findByUserName(principal.getName());
    thingGroupService.update(thingGroup, user);
}
```

And the corresponding `thingGroupService` which is `@Transactional`

```
@Override
@Transactional
public ThingGroup update(final ThingGroup thingGroup, User user){
    ThingGroup found = null;
    try {
        found = find(thingGroup.getId(),user);

        found.setName(thingGroup.getName());

        found = getDao().save(found);

    } catch (final DataIntegrityViolationException e) {

        // I want to throw that custom exception here

        MyBadRequestException ex = new MyBadRequestException("MyBadRequestException.update.violation.thingGroup", "violation_data_integrity");
        ex.setParameters(new Object[] { thingGroup.getName()});
        throw ex;
    }
    return found;
}
```

In the MySQL underlying database I have a constraint of unicity on the name of the thingGroup.

So if I try to update a thingGroup with an existing name, it should fail.

When it fails, I'd like to throw a custom exception to pass an understandable message to the controller layer.

My problem is that, because of the `@Transactional` annotation, the Hibernate exceptions are thrown after the transaction has been committed, which means after the service method has returned (I think).

And that means I can't catch the exception in the service layer.

I have search for answers like that and as I have understood, I would need to catch the exception in the Controller layer. However it doesn't seem to be a good solution, because the controller layer would have to be aware of the underlying behavior of the service layer, which is not good.

Is there some general solution to this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually [flush](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush%28%29) the modifications to the database to force the constraint violation to occur before the automatic flush which happens at the end of the transaction.

Comment: Will automatic rollbacks still work properly if I chain several @Transactionnal service methods using saveAndFlush and one of them fails ?

Comment: Sure, flush just synchronizes the current modifications (executes DMLs) in the database, it does not commit the transaction.

Comment: I've replaced `save` with `saveAndFlush` wherever I needed it. It has solved my issue. Now the exception is properly catched in the service layer and I can throw a custom application exception to the controller layer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to move the actual transaction out of this service method into a separate method. This way the transaction is committed before you leave your service method, and you can react to Hibernate exceptions.

```
@Override
public ThingGroup update(final ThingGroup thingGroup, User user){
    ThingGroup found = null;
    try {
        return doUpdate(thingGroup, user)
    } catch (final DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        // I want to throw that custom exception here
        MyBadRequestException ex = new MyBadRequestException("MyBadRequestException.update.violation.thingGroup", "violation_data_integrity");
        ex.setParameters(new Object[] { thingGroup.getName()});
        throw ex;
    }
    return found;
}

@Transactional
public ThingGroup doUpdate(final ThingGroup thingGroup, User user){
    ThingGroup found = find(thingGroup.getId(),user);
    found.setName(thingGroup.getName());
    found = getDao().save(found);
    return found;
}
```

The method doUpdate here is public for

a. easier unit testing and

b. the possibility to use transactions, if you don't use aspects.

Comment: It will break the transaction propagation between the different service methods called from update. Here I have written a simple service method but in the real application I have some service methods that calls several other service methods, which require transaction propagation to keep data integrity correct.

Comment: Then your methods would have to know whether they were called from "outside" or via chaining. That would be ugly. What about doing the chaining via the "internal" (doSomething) methods, and let the (interface) service methods handle the external calls?

Comment: Thank for the suggestions but it is not a convenient solution. It would clutter all the service classes with duplicated methods ( method and doMethod). I can't believe there is no other way. Catching exceptions in @Transactionnal methods seem to be an obvious issue to me. There must be a clean way to handle that but I'm not familiar enough with Hibernate.